# Select the top X rows from a table ignoring the first Y rows

Tags: mysql, sql

If I want to retrieve the first 10 rows from a table that's the code I would use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Persons
LIMIT 10
```

What I want to know is how can I retrieve 10 results that are after the first 10.

If I do this code below ill get the results that I want, but the first 10 rows will be unnecessary:

```
SELECT *
FROM Persons
LIMIT 20
```

So how can I ignore the first 10 results and get only the next ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the starting record and the duration if you want to get the next 10 values.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Persons
LIMIT  10, 10
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de3c9/1)

Other Source:

- [MySQL LIMIT](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

Comment: I have added a demo on my answer `:D`

Answer (score 0):

Per the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) you can specify an *offset* for limit (indexed from 1).  There are two valid syntaxes:

```
SELECT cols FROM t1 LIMIT 10, 10
SELECT cols FROM t1 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Note that in the first one the `OFFSET` is actually the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage to use this,

```
SELECT *
FROM   Persons
LIMIT  10, OFFSET 10;
```

Because, the biggest problem these days is code readability. This is a little bit readable.